# Self-injectivity of quotients of polynomial rings by zero-dimensional ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, ideals, homological-algebra

Let $A = \Bbbk[x_1, \dots , x_n]$ for some field $\Bbbk$, and let $I$ be an ideal contained $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$.

> If $A/I$ is finite dimensional, is it necessarily self-injective?

[This answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/58399/78095) seems to indicate that if we pass to the completion then the answer is "yes". Can we then infer (using associated graded etc.) that the same must be true of $A/I$?

Comment: @user26857: Sorry, despite me typing $\Bbbk[x,y]/(x,y)^2$ I'd assumed we were dealing with $\Bbbk[x,y]/(x^2,y^2)$.

Comment: @lokodiz The example given by Mariano was answering part of the original question which was edited to something completely different after he posted his answer (I wish people wouldn't do that without at least pointing out how it affects existing answers!).

Comment: But isn't the socle of $\Bbbk[x,y]/(x^2,y^2)$ just $\Bbbk xy$, and so $\Bbbk[x,y]/(x^2,y^2)$ is Gorenstein?

Comment: Sorry, I wrongly thought that the editing of the other question was contributing to the confusion about Mariano's answer, but you're right, it is Gorenstein/self-injective. (But I still wish people wouldn't do that!)